# How to send the json data response to the particular Url(Server) from Servlet?

Tags: html, json, servlets

I have the following code which is with json format data as input variables in the html form.

```
out.write("<html><body onload=\"document.forms[0].submit()\">\n");
      out.write("<form  enctype='application/json' method=\"POST\" action=\"" + resourcePath + "\">\n");
      out.write("<input name='sessionId' value=\"" + sessionId + "\"/>\n");
      out.write("<input name='sessionValid' value=\"" + true + "\"/>\n");
      out.write("</form>\n</body>\n</html>\n");
```

I have googled about this and i got the above format but it is not working, still it is taking as a normal string while reading after form has been submitted. I have seen same type of questions in stack overflow also but they are directing me to use jquery which i do not want to use.

What might be the wrong in the above code?

Comment: First off, try to produce a jsFiddle so we can see your working example.. Second, do you have the ability to use ajax? This would allow you to serialise the form and also send a json object as well.. Alot easier and better method for expansion later on. I do also note you dont want to use jquery... But thats not required in this case.. Do you have PHP/server side languages available? or just raw HTML pages?

Comment: right now i can not use ajax in my code. I don't hwo to produce jsFiddle for the code

Comment: Have you checked your browsers console for any script / request errors? Normally F12 in most modern browsers.. also refer to http://darobin.github.io/formic/specs/json/ if you have not already

Comment: @Mayhem, Please check the edited question title which is my actual requirement

Comment: Is "resourcePath" a valid variable, ... using my example below.. If you manually enter the value of resourcePath into action=""... does it work as expected?

Comment: Ok it will not work, it might work because of syntax errors. but please see how to send json data to the specific url(server) in servlet

Comment: a servlet will simply response/process a HTTP request... So if the basic static form does not work as expected.. Its a backend issue with the servlet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74546/discussion-between-m-s-naidu-and-mayhem).

Comment: I tried, form is working as expected but i am not getting the response in the form of JSON, it is coming in the form of normal key:value pair

Answer (score 0):

Its very hard to tell with the current example given, it would seem there is more of a syntax error or possibly some issue with the browser or submitting to the server side.

Here is a bare basic example that can be tested if you have PHP... just create a test.php file or something and use the following code. If this works, then it would be the variables used or the way they are being created/echoed in place.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_REQUEST['sessionId'])) {
        echo "<pre>".print_r($_REQUEST, true)."</pre>";
        exit;
    }
?>
<form enctype='application/json' method="POST">
    <input name='sessionId' value="has7ft8f7w56ef78wte"/>
    <input name='sessionValid' value="true"/>
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

If you can provide some more information, i'll do what i can to help out in this case.. Some times when things dont work.. best to go back to basics for testing then see where it breaks.

**EDIT**

```
<form enctype='application/json' method="POST" action="myurl_or_where_ever">
    <input name='sessionId' value="has7ft8f7w56ef78wte"/>
    <input name='sessionValid' value="true"/>
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

By testing with something as simple as this, you're making sure the basic concept works.. If this works, then change the action="" first.. if that works, then change the sessionId/Valid.. The button is to simply rule out the onload event.. This is part of debugging and will save you alot of time in the future.

Replace "myurl_or_where_ever" with the expected value of "resourcePath"

Comment: I don't have php and Please see my edited question and i do not want to put my any submit button.

Comment: Basically this is just a simple manual test... Will update answer in a second.. But try creating a static version of the form.. So no variables, no out.write.. Just a plain HTML file that uses the submit button to submit the form to a pre-defined action/url.. This rules out the syntax, dynamic aspect.

Comment: I tried, form is working as expected but i am not getting the response in the form of JSON, it is coming in the form of normal key:value pair

Comment: So its not an issue with the form/url as such.. What code are you using for the servlet side of things.. My guess is what ever handles the HTTP request is converting JSON to another format.. I generally steer clear of anything Java.. But post/update if you can your servlet handler for the post.

Comment: is my enctype='application/json' not working properly?

Comment: Possibly, using PHP as an example (as i develop in that).. If i post JSON data to it, i simply receive it still as a key-pair value.. Your receiving backend may convert this automatically.. PHP will do this and i would need to do something lile json_encode($_REQUEST) to make PHP see it as JSON.. This could simply be normal behaviour

Comment: Are you getting in the form of ({key:value}) at receiver side

Comment: "If i post JSON data to it" you meant that using above html form?